# Django After-deployment errors

Tags: javascript, html, django, web-deployment, meta-tags

i recently made a site, following this tutorial https://pythonprogramming.net/django-web-development-python-tutorial . I have uploaded it, however now in the meta-description shows me this:

"For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript. Here are the instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser"

The site is made from django.Do you know where the mistake might be? The site is http://birminghamcleaner.co.uk/ .

[This is an image, of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaXKm.jpg)

Comment: Enable the javascript in the browser eg chrome, Microsoft edge etc

Comment: Follow up this link to enable javascript in your browser https://www.enablejavascript.io/en

Comment: My browser has javascript enablede. I have tried and with other devices. Please have a look at the image that i uploaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this part. Remove it and you're golden:

```
<noscript> Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript! </noscript>
```

Long answer:

Google's crawler tries to parse pages in plain HTML, without executing Javascript (I can't say with 100% certainty their rules on Javascipt parsing, because the code is proprietary).

However, you do have some code that is executed only if Javascript is disabled. Just remove it and it'll be fine.

Comment: So i deleted, but its still the same. Am not sure but i think the problem lies somewhere with the meta tag.

Comment: It takes some time for google crawler to reindex your page, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, please remove this meta tag as well: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`

Comment: Okey, i removed it. Do you know how much time it takes (approximately)? I don't want to raise a fuss over nothing. Also i found this after searching https://forum.webflow.com/t/for-full-functionality-of-this-site-it-is-necessary-to-enable-javascript-problem/142934.

Comment: That is for webflow, its idea is to simplify having a web page. Kinda like wordpress.com. 

If you want to improve how google is searching your website, your best bet is https://search.google.com/search-console/about

Also, if you found this answer useful, please upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, i did upvote but it will show when i have more than 15 reputation apparently.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Please tell me later if it worked, okay?

Comment: Yeah i had to wait for google to crawl it. Thanks.